# vCenter Appliance IP address and it's gateway are not in the same subnet error

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I am trying to deploy a vCenter Server Appliance on a OVH ESXI 6.7
For those who know, OVH ip addresses and default gateways are at different subnets.

for example, if your dedicated server has an ip of 172.172.172.172 then the default gateway must be 172.172.172.254 for the VM inside of this host.

In my scenario, let's say my default gateway is 172.172.172.254 and I have arranged the appliance ip address as 37.37.37.1 and netmask is 255.255.255.255

But when I try to make an installation with my settings, installation does not continue with following error: **IP Address and it's gateway are not in same subnets**

I will try to set network configuration later on but if is there a solution for this problem, I would love to know.

Comment: The gateway is the host on the network that knows how to reach other networks. The gateway must be on the same network. If the gateway is on a different network, then you would need a gateway to reach the gateway.

Comment: > In my scenario, let's say my default gateway is 172.172.172.254 and I have arranged the appliance ip address as 37.37.37.1 and netmask is 255.255.255.255
This doesn't make any sense *at all*.

Comment: @RonMaupin in general, but there are setups different. For example with Online.net you can get "failover IP" addresses for your box, but their documentation says "Note that we now have a unique Gateway for all your VMs! It's 62.210.0.1." (https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/network/ip-failover/virtual-machine), while the IP blocks are ` 62.210.0.0/16 & 195.154.0.0/16 & 212.83.128.0/18 `. But then it uses Virtual MAC Addresses for each VMs.

Answer (score 2):

The Default Gateway needs to be in the same network as the host using that Default Gateway. Otherwise, how would the host reach it?

Why are you assigning the appliance an ip address in another network?

Comment: Because it is an a huge data center and data center network configuration works like this. OVH additional IP Addresses run in that way. I think there should be a VLAN or I should create another switch.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: the default gateway can be in a different subnet on non-RFC compliant networks. Some providers, such as OVH, developed their own routing internal routing protocols and firmware in order to optimise IPv4 addressing.

In such networks, the gateway is apparently outside the subnet. Such as:

Host: 192.168.0.1 
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 
Gateway: 192.168.200.254

If we are in a regular network, that setting is wrong. But in OVH network, it works and this is what you should configure. When the host tries to reach the gateway, the packet is intercepted by the first router that makes sure it will be responded to accordingly.

I have plenty of servers Windows/Linux configured this way at OVH.

All this to say, the question of the OP is valid.